# What does html5 and css3 depend on?

Tags: html, css

Do html5 and css3 functionalities depend on the browser (only)? I just need this cleared, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 and CSS3 depend on recent browsers.

Certain syntax from HTML5 and CSS3 are supported in certain browsers, others not.

You don't need to "install" anything to start using either languages, they are entirely dependant on the browser supporting / being able to render the code.

for HTML5 , you need to put the following at the top of your HTML document to declare that you are using HTML5:

```
<!doctype HTML>
```

Here is a great compatibility chart to see where HTML5 and CSS3 work and on what browsers:
http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/

http://fmbip.com/

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, that answers all of my questions.